# How can I animate a bandsaw blade?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, parent

I would like to model a bandsaw blade cutting into a piece of wood. I don't need/want to model the whole saw. I just want to see the blade (a continuous band) rotate/spin around in an oval as it approaches the wood. How can I animate this?

I have shaped a cube into a long, thin mesh for the blade. I thought I could parent the blade to an empty, have the empty follow a curve (an oval), and then add a curve modifier to make the blade into an oval.

This didn't work as I had hoped. I've added a link to a screen capture to show what happened.

https://whitanderson.com/blender/bandsaw/index.html

I am using Blender 2.8.

Thanks for any help you can give me in understanding what did happen, and how I can create the animation I would like.

--Whit

Comment: Have you tried an object with an Array modifier and a Curve modifier? Then you just need to move your object and it will move along the curve....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as explained by Jackdaw, except you could begin with an *Array* modifier:

- Create your module object.
- Create your blade profile with a curve.
- Put your object on the curve.
- Give your object an *Array* modifier. To get the exact amount of iterations you can choose *Fit Type* > *Fit Curve* and choose your curve as *Curve*. Or you can simply choose *Fixed Count* and set the right *Count* value. Choose the good axis in the *Relative Offset* field.
- Give your object a *Curve* modifier. Choose your curve as *Object*.
- Now to animate your blade, move your object on the Y (or X) axis.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your saw blade mesh should use the same position as the curve as a resting position. The blade should be aligned to the Deformation Axis (X by default).
[image]

When you then animate the blade mesh object position along the Deformation Axis (X), the blade will move along the curve.

[image]

One extra note: This doesn't work well with the Bounds Clamp option on the curve.